# Powershell - email free space information

Tags: windows, email, powershell

i am currently using:

```
$emailFrom = "user@host.com"
$emailTo = "destination@host.com"
$subject = "subject"
$body = "message"
$smtpServer = "mail.host.com"
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $body)
```

and i know that with the folowing command i can find out the free space on all of my hdd:

```
Get-WmiObject WIN32_logicaldisk | sort -desc freespace | select -first 3 | format-table -autosize deviceid,devicetype,providername,freespace,size,volumename;
```

when i try to do this:

```
$body = Get-WmiObject WIN32_logicaldisk | sort -desc freespace | select -first 3 | format-table -autosize deviceid,devicetype,providername,freespace,size,volumename;
```

but all i get in my email is the folowing:

```
    Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

how can i get my free space via email using powershell???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

$body = Get-WmiObject WIN32_logicaldisk | sort -desc freespace | select -first 3 | format-table -autosize deviceid,devicetype,providername,freespace,size,volumename | out-string

I've just tried it on my PC and it worked.

For some background on why this works see:

http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/how-does-select-string-work-with-pipelines-of-objects.aspx

JR

Comment: +1 - out-string is a good trick; that's going in my bag of tricks.

Comment: out-string is the answer.  You can't really use format-table if you're assigning...it's really meant for output to the console.

Comment: works like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
$body_array = Get-WmiObject WIN32_logicaldisk | sort -desc freespace | select -first 3 | format-table -autosize deviceid,devicetype,providername,freespace,size,volumename;
$body = $body_array.ToString();
```

Comment: nope. ain't working, all i get in my email now it's 

System.Object[]

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly adapt from my post in [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/13426/easy-way-to-monitor-disk-space-on-multiple-ms-2003-servers/13440#13440).

Comment: i will try, but i haven't been able to email the contents of a variable like   $body = Get-WmiObject WIN32_logicaldisk  i assume there's someting i am missing, but i must mention i have just started using powershell last week

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is taking a stream of objects from Get-WMIObject, sorting and selecting a subset, then producing a text rendition of the remaining objects-- not just working with pure text. If you want to get a pure text rendition, you can just change your call to format-table to use select-object instead.